# Aforge: fourier transform using C#

Tags: c#, fft, aforge

I'm trying to do fourier transform using Aforge. According to the documentation, This code should work.

```
Bitmap a1 = new Bitmap("c://z3.bmp");
ComplexImage complexImage1 = ComplexImage.FromBitmap(a1);
complexImage1.ForwardFourierTransform();
Bitmap fourierImage = complexImage1.ToBitmap();
fourierImage.Save("c:/z2.bmp");
```

For some reason, a weird error come up saying : "  Image width and height should be power of 2." I have no idea what that means, the code should perfectly work. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the error you will have to use an image whose widht and height are a power of 2.

Enlarge your image by padding it with zeroes so it is exactly (2,4,8,16,256,512,1024,...) pixels high and wide before calling the fourier transformation.

The standard fast fourier algorithm works only for these dimensions. Some implementations enlarge the image internally if it does not match, looks like Aforge does not.

I think Aforge uses the standard .net graphics classes, so you could do something like this:

```
    using (Bitmap large = new Bitmap(widthPOWER_OF_2, heightPOWER_OF_2, PixelFormat.YOUR_FORMAT))
    using (Graphics largeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(large))
    {
        largeGraphics.DrawImage(smallbitmap, 0 , 0); 
     }
   }
```

Comment: how to enlarge the image? 
plus if i change the size, the properties would change i suppose ( the fourier transformation )
how to do fourier transformation for an image without needing to do this enlarging ?

Comment: If you fill in the missing rows and columns with zeroes, your results should be as as expected. I am certain Aforge provides some tools to copy an image into a larger matrix. If for some reason you need to do a fourier transformation without enlarging your image, it gets complicated, see for example http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/745/3799

Comment: okay i agree with you, enlarging would be easier, but i couldn't find anything at all to help me in padding zeroes to the images to make them larger

Comment: I am not very familiar with aforge, but you should be able to do so using the standard .net bitmap methods